# Книга по OpenGL

Tags: книги, opengl

Подскажите пожалуйста более-менее актуальную книгу по OpenGL желательно чтобы там была расписана работа с шейдерами и их встраивание в приложение , можно C++ или Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Довольно доходчиво изложены основы OpenGL в [этой](http://esate.ru/blog/knigi-po-opengl/167.html) книге.

По шейдерам лучше отдельную книгу читать, например эту: "OpenGL. Трехмерная графика и язык программирования шейдеров. Для профессионалов"

А ещё [тут](http://pmg.org.ru/nehe/index.html) есть несколько полезных уроков.

А вообще, я бы порекомменодовал Вам пользоваться XNA 4 + с#. Но выбор, в основном, зависит от целей Вашего проекта.

Comment: XNA уже пробовал довольно хорошая вещь практически закончил арканоид но есть одна бида связанная с особенностями NET а так полностью с вами согласен , жду пока на моно XNA перенесут))

Comment: и спасибо за ссылки ознакомлюсь , правда золотая книга у меня есть в бумажном варианте но она немного не актуальна на сегоднешний день , разве что там хорошая теоретическая база

Comment: Ждать долго не пришлось:)
  http://www.monoxna.org

Comment: 0_0 спасибо добрый человек , не знал такого думал ещё в проекте :))
PS
и как пользовались ? всё тоже осталось как и в XNA ?

Comment: Как использовать - не знаю, не пробовал, но на сайте разработчика по-моему всё описано.

Comment: никак немогу ссылку на скачивание найти , сейчас буду рыть в гугле ))

Comment: "...основы OpenGL в этой книге" ссылка не работает - 404 =(

Answer (score 0):

Есть ещё OpenGL суперкнига. Последнее переведённое на русский 3-е издание. Там описывается OpenGL 2.0. Я думаю, что его возможностей вполне хватит. Если же нет, то читай 5-е издание на английском. Там уже есть OpenGL 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

- OpenGl red book - больше справочная
- OpenGl orange book - шейдеры
- OpenGl blue book - туториалы
- OpenGl insights - особенности, которых часто нет в документациях

желательно, начиная с 3.2, потому что ранние уже не актуальны.