# Какие книги стоит почитать дабы углубиться в GameDev?

Tags: java, разработка-игр, книги

Хотелось бы погрузиться в GameDev, но без опоры сложновато... К примеру только сегодня я узнал о существовании такой штуки как *Ray Casting* и она мне очень помогла... Особенно если бы я узнал об этом раньше :)
Так вот, хотелось бы узнать какие книги стоит почитать дабы углубиться в GameDev в общем и/или в рамках языка Java

Comment: Ray Casting знать совершенно не обязательно. А вот OpenGL очень даже желательно

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/27728/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-opengl

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, ответ будет сильно зависеть от мнения отвечающего.

От себя и около темы:

Лично я считаю, что хорошо в какой-то теме по книжке не разберешься. Поэтому нужно взять реальную задачу, с которой вам почти по силам справиться, а все, что вы не знаете, найти по мере продвижения.

К примеру, хотите вы написать крестики-нолики. Знаете, как отрисовать спрайты, но не знаете, как обработать клик по ним, как сделать анимацию. Берете и разбираетесь.

Если вы хотите именно книгу - их не мало. От себя не посоветую, ибо я их довольно много перелистал и почерпнул лишь каплю, но совет - не ищите книгу на русском, если вы в состоянии читать на английском. На английском материала больше и зачастую он качественнее (не в обиду русскому геймдев-комьюнити).

У меня сейчас есть какой-то опыт разработки игр, однако часто приходится сталкиваться с тем, с чем ещё не сталкивался. В таких случаях я часто копаюсь в документации Unity, смотрю, как у них примерно реализована фича, которая мне нужна.

Также многое становится на свои места, когда вы смотрите исходный код. Если пишете на чем-то вроде libgdx, то вам никто не запрещает смотреть в исходники, и часто можно найти реализацию интересующей вас функции и многое узнать.

[Вот](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/1265) ссылка на англоязычный so с перечнем книг, смысла дублировать их в этом посте не вижу.

И вам, конечно же, терпения и удачи, ибо они имеют важную роль в становлении разработчика игр. По себе знаю, когда что-то крутое получается сделать самому, желание делать ещё больше взлетает до небес)

Comment: Подскажите, разве java и gamdev востребованы на сегодняшний день?(Не свои проекты естественно)

Comment: @ВладЛеонидов пока вы, ваши друзья или кто-то ещё играет в игры, геймдев будет востребован. Более того, если хорошо попасть, можно иметь неплохую зарплату. Вот только конкуренция все больше и больше, а со времён ведьмака 3 я так ни во что годное и не поиграл... Что касается java - это мобильные игры, в основном. Для пк это сильно большая роскошь - заставлять игрока качать jvm. Может когда-нибудь java native будет довольно распространен, но пока что java - это андроид игры. А для пк - c++ для AAA игр и c# для игр попроще...

Comment: полностью согласен, просто меня интересует вопрос реально ли найти работу как java разработчик(gamedev) пусть даже на android, с десктопом понятно, что java пролетает, просто сколько не видел вакансий gamedev'a все они для unity/c# или c++

Comment: @ВладЛеонидов хех, в этом плане не подскажу) я лишь начинаю учиться, и для себя работу ещё не искал. А истории знакомых слишком разнятся от одного к другому. Но думаю, тут будет играть больше даже везение, чем ваш скилл, ибо жаба-дроид-разработчиков не мало...